# Using styled-components to style my own React components

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I am trying to use styled-components to style my own child components.

As an example, I have created a custom card component, called myCard, as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import Card, { CardActions, CardContent } from "material-ui/Card";
import Button from "material-ui/Button";
import Typography from "material-ui/Typography";

const myCard = props => {
  return (
    <Card>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography>{props.cardName}</Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small">SELECT</Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default myCard;
```

Now, in the parent component, I want to reuse this myCard component but with the possibility of giving any one of them a custom style, such as a border (when I eventually refactor the code to onClick):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Grid from "material-ui/Grid";
import styled from "styled-components";
import myCard from "./myCard";


const StyledCard = styled(myCard)`
  /* border-style: ${props => (props.border ? "solid" : "none")}; */
  border-style: solid !important;
  border-width: 5px;
  width: 180px;
`;

class cardSelect extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Grid container spacing={24}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Grid container justify="center">
              <Grid item>
                <StyledCard
                  cardName="Bronze"
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <StyledCard
                  cardName="Silver"
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <StyledCard
                  cardName="Gold"
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default cardSelect;
```

I admit, I find the styled-components documentation rather poor. And there is only one reference to this kind of situation, which suggests to pass the className prop to the component. However I am not truly understanding this concept.

Comment: Hiya, can you open an issue on the styles-components-website repo please? It’d be great to identify the problem that you had and improve the docs

Comment: ok I will document my findings on their github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer through trials and errors. Could not find this solution (at least holistic) anywhere, so for posterity and the benefit of others, this is how I solved it.

The solution is simply to pass the **className** prop to the **myCard** component as follows:

```
const myCard = props => {
  const { className } = props;
  return (
    <Card className={className}>
...
```

So, in general, one has to pass the className prop on to the custom component that you want to render.

Answer (score 1):

Pass props with notations to your `{...props}` Card component.

```
import React from "react";
import Card, { CardActions, CardContent } from "material-ui/Card";
import Button from "material-ui/Button";
import Typography from "material-ui/Typography";

const myCard = props => {
  return (
    /**Here, pass the props with spread notation */
    <Card {...props}>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography>{props.cardName}</Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small">SELECT</Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default myCard;
```

So actually, what does this spread props do when you pass any prop to the component it will become part of the component.

Answer (score 1):

So you really need to pass `className` prop to the `Card` component. The styled-components generates classes for you, to apply styles for `not-styled-components` just needs to pass className prop to the component...

```
const myCard = props => {
  return (
    <Card className={props.className}>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography>{props.cardName}</Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small">SELECT</Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};
```